# Can not run ashx in area in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, handler

When I run a test generic handler (.ashx) in root folder in renders fine. But after moving it to an area called Panel, I am getting 404 resourse not found error.

Is it about route ? What am I missing?

Comment: Is this an Asp.NET MVc project ? Why are you running ashx handler in that ?

Comment: Yes It is Mvc Razor engine. I am simply trying to integrate ajax image upload which uses generic handler. What is wrong with it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. You can upload files using asp.net mvc controllers as well. It is pretty easy. No need to add ashx handlers.

Comment: Yes I know but why it is not running in areas but in root?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by using full physical path to ashx file.